# How to upgrade node js to a specific version in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, node.js, software-update

I want to upgrade node js to v10.15. How can I do it with or without command prompt in Windows-10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to upgrade node js to v10.15

Go to [Previous Releases | Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/). There you will see download options for all previous versions, including 10.15:

> [image]

Click on "Downloads":

> [image]

You probably want to download either `node-v10.15.0-x64.msi` or `node-v10.15.0-x86.msi`  depending on whether you have a 32 or 64 bit version of Windows 10.

Run the `msi` installer to install version 10.15.

Comment: my system is 64 bit. Is `node-v10.15.3-win-x64` good?

Comment: It should be. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). It should allow you to install any node version